pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1URL invalid, extra characters found after valid URL:
I'm trying to read a text file into a document array or text url using Python, but I keep getting an error.
My code:
doc = MyText(
    url="C:\\Users\\User\\PycharmProjects\\vector_database_using_vectordb\games.txt"
)

doc.text = doc.url.load("C:\\Users\\User\\PycharmProjects\\vector_database_using_vectordb\games.txt")

assert doc.text.startswith('<TITLE>Read Me>/TITLE')

model for MyText:
'''
# Store text representation by defining schema.
# class MyText(BaseDoc):
#     text: str = None
#     url: TextUrl = None
'''
I get the following error
    doc = MyText(
  File "pydantic\main.py", line 341, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.__init__
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for MyText
url
  URL invalid, extra characters found after valid URL: ':\\Users\\User\\PycharmProjects\\vector_database_using_vectordb\\games.txt' (type=value_error.url.extra; extra=:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\vector_database_using_vectordb\games.txt)

I have tried removing the extra characters and including a validator similar to the one provided as a solution in the post: How to accept urls without a protocol?, but have still received the same error.

"I have tried removing the extra characters." - and what happened then?

I have received the same error after removing the extra characters.

pelase show the model MyText, also if i guessed it right, you are trying to validate a Path while youre actually validating Url

After reading the documentation for Docarray I thought the URL was the path to the file.

I have added the model MyText.

I think you've confused between adding pydantic valdation for FilePaths and are instead using AnyURL.
In any way u can also try the following improvements.

Use raw string instead of the actual string. Using r"A/B" is better than "A/B" because of the special characters.
Try constructing a Posixpath using Pathlib instead of just a string.

NOTE : Please dont forget to add an MRE or in this case a Minimum, Reproducible Code Example to your question/edit your question.

Why is r"A//B" better than "A/B"?

r stands for a raw string in python. A string when interpreted raw does not encode the special characters (\ - backslash) into something completely different - which is called the escape character.
It's like for denoting newline you use \n wherein \ is used before n to denote newlines. Similar is the case for \t, \s etc.
For denoting and \ in a normal string however, you can use \ (double backslash) here the first \ acts as an escape character and the second actually tells python to look for a backslash.
